# url-pattern and wildcards

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web.xml

While configuring the security constraints for a web-module's roles in J2EE application I'm having the following problem:

### Application:

Giving a servlet named **customersServlet**, which receives two parameters in the URL:

- A string representing an operation (INS, UPD, DLT and DSP).
- An identification number to identify a customer on which the operation will be performed.

E.G.: the url `/servlet/cusotmersServlet?UPD,5` is used to update customer number 5 data, and the url `/servlet/customersServlet?DLT,8` is used to delete customer number 8.

### Problem:

If I use this security-constraint the servlet can only be accessed by the role specified, which is ok:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>...</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/clientsServlet*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>clientAdmin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But  I want to restrict the ability to insert customers only to a role named **clientAdmin**.

I've tried several url patterns but none of them works as I want (all of them allow every role to access the servlet with any parameter):

```
<url-pattern>/servlet/clientsServlet?INS,*</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/servlet/clientsServlet?INS/*</url-pattern>
...
```

**How to use the wildcard `*` in the `url-pattern` tag?**

Note: The **application** cannot be changed, so I need a solution that only implies touching the deployment descriptor.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `<url-pattern>` tag only allows a very restricted subset of wildcards. This is probably not what you are used to from other situations, where a `*` can be used at any position. You can download the Servlet specification here:

http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr154/index2.html

Section SRV.11.2 of that document describes how these URL patterns are interpreted. In particular, the `*` does *not* mean "zero or more arbitrary characters" here.

Comment: Thank you. My solution was to change `/someText*` to `/someText/*` and of course change the url patterns of the 'someText' servlets to match that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: The application cannot be changed, so I need a solution that only implies touching the deployment descriptor.

Not sure if this counts as an application change - perhaps you could think of it as a plug-in. You could add a [`Filter`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html). This would require the ability to add a new JAR to *WEB-INF/libs* and the ability to define the filter in *web.xml*. The `Filter` would allow you to restrict access programmatically.